# How to delete lines if next line begins with the same content?

Tags: parsing, sed, duplicates

As an example the file with following content:

```
My dog
My dog is running
My dog is running fast
A cat
A cat is black
A cat is black and small
```

As a result I want to have only this two lines:

```
My dog is running fast
A cat is black and small
```

I would prefer to do it in one line command.

Tried many SED, AWK and UNIQ options but could not find a good solution.
I guess SED should be able to do it if it can read lines by two and print first line only if second line does not match it. But, cannot figure out how to do it.

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Please edit your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: `Tried many SED, AWK and UNIQ` What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 'N;/^(.*)\n\1/!P;D' file
```

Use `-E` option to make regexp easier.

Append the next line.

If the whole of the first line matches the start of the next line, do not print the first line.

Otherwise, print the first line and then always delete it and repeat.

N.B. The `D` command is special in that it deletes up to and including the first newline (if there is one), anything remaining causes the normal cycle not to fetch the next line and then then next cycle uses whatever is leftover.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
sed -n ':a;$!N;s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\1/\1/;$!ta;P;D'
```

- `:a` - label a
- `$!N` - if not last line read next line (in additional to the one already read)
- `s/^\([^\n]*\)\n\1/\1/` - If the pattern is found that the next line starts with the previous line, remove the previous line.
- `$!ta` - if it's not the last line and the last `s` command found the pattern, jump to label a (loop)
- `P` print from the pattern space up until a newline
- `D` remove from pattern space up until a newline, and start from the beginning, without reading the next line

Comment: It is really working. Thanks a lot.
Now I would need to understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Leverage a dummy `substr()` wrapper in `awk` to perform value-swapping between `$0` and `last` (`__`) without any arithmetic, bitwise XOR, user-defined function call, temp scalar variable, or temp array. The data types of the swapped pair don't need to match at all.

```
 echo '
My dog
My dog is running
My dog is running fast
A cat
A cat is black
A cat is black and small' |
```

> ```
> mawk 'END { print __ } index($_, __) - (__ = $_ substr("", $_ = __))^_'
> ```

```
 1  My dog is running fast
 2  A cat is black
```

Answer (score 0):

Using any awk:

```
$ awk 'index($0,prev) != 1{print prev} {prev=$0} END{print prev}' file
My dog is running fast
A cat is black and small
```

I'm using `index()` to ensure a string rather than regexp comparison so it won't fail if/when any of your lines contain regexp metachars and I'm testing for `== 1` to ensure it won't fail if/when the previous line exists in the current line but not at the start of it.